# Performing tasks at different times for different users after subscriptions

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, azure

So here is the problem statement. I have a service which services mobile devices. Each user on the trigger of an event sends message to the service to register itself. After which the service performs a particular set of tasks at regular intervals(say 5 min) from the time of registration. So the execution time will be different for each user based on registration time.

I Implemented this using threads and Timers, it worked to an extent but as the users increased, the threads are killed and the tasks are not completed. Also this service is hosted on azure. I have created a WCF service with WebHtpp binding which accepts and returns JSON data.

Web jobs are a suggestion given to me. But since the execution times vary I am unable to use that as well. Is it even possible to perform such a task using C# and asp.net or am i going i the wrong direction entirely.

Comment: Why not set a fixed interval: create a process that performs the tasks for all registered devices at that time. So once a device is registered it will have to wait for up to 4.99 minutes before the tasks for that device will be started. This way you do not have to keep a lot of timers or something alike.

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify where's the bottleneck that stops your threads before completion.

I would solve this using another approach: every new user, put a message in a queue, and create one Azure Function to dequeue the message and perform the logic of your service. This way your application will scale better, and you'll save money with the serverless approach.